# Is monitoring rsync with a pts device possible?

Tags: rsync, monitoring, tty

I have a rsync backup script, and I was wondering about methods of monitoring it as it runs. I could have it save a log and use watch and tail, but I had a more elegant solution in mind that might be possible. I'm just not sure how it would be done.

Would it be possible to get rsync to run on it's own pts device, and run a command to monitor that device? It's not an area I'm familiar on, and any information about how this would be done or why it couldn't would be a valuable lesson for me.

Comment: How is what you propose different from running rsync in a screen / tmux / dtach session?

Comment: Depending on the typical (or possible but supposed to be handled without problems) output of the script it may be necessary to adapt the size of `screen`'s history (probably `tmux` has a similar feature).

Comment: "watch and tail"? Maybe just `tail -f`.

Comment: What about these methods using `strace` or `lsof`? http://askubuntu.com/questions/323775/monitor-watch-running-rsync-process

Comment: Using screen could work, but the task runs on cron, perhaps someone could answer how screen can be started detached but running a process. Then I could just attach to it, it would answer the question quite well.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned screen could work for you.

```
screen -d -m /path/to/script.sh
```

This will open screen, start the script and detach.

Execute `screen -r` to show a list of sessions you can reconnect to.